# Why I faild to fetch latest version of R in Debian?

Tags: linux, r, debian

I want to upgrade my current R version which is 2.15.1 to latest version of R in Debian wheezy, I tried following steps, but unfortunatly I was not succesful.
Step1 : I added following two lines to end of  at the end of "/etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
deb-src http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
```

then I run this commands on the terminal:

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 06F90DE5381BA480

gpg -a --export 06F90DE5381BA480 |sudo apt-key add
```

and finally run :

```
apt-get update

aptitude -t wheezy-cran3 install r-base r-base-dev
```

But I get following error:

```
Ign ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de wheezy/non-free Translation-en                                                                                    
Fetched 162 kB in 8s (19.0 kB/s)                                                                                                              
W: Failed to fetch http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/linux/debian/wheezy-cran3/Sources  301  Moved Permanently

W: Failed to fetch http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/linux/debian/wheezy-cran3/Packages  301  Moved Permanently

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
lap-97-35:/etc/apt# aptitude -t wheezy-cran3 install r-base r-base-dev
E: The value 'wheezy-cran3' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
E: The value 'wheezy-cran3' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Would someone can help me to fix this ?

Comment: official debian wheezy repository has version 2.5.1, so why do not you install it from there? (i am not familiar with R)

Comment: Have you tried other mirrors? Check [the mirror list](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html)